# How can I fix charset problem in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm building website with ReactJS. And I'm using this template: https://github.com/DesignRevision/shards-dashboard-react I deployed the site but I have charset problem in turkish characters. For example, 'Büyük Bilgi Bankası' word seems 'B�y�k Bilgi Bankas�'

I tried to set charset in head tags. However, it didn't worked.

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

or

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1254" />
```

This is my code..

```
        <div className="d-table m-auto">
          <img
            id="main-logo"
            className="d-inline-block align-top mr-1"
            style={{ maxWidth: "25px" }}
            src={require("../../../images/shards-dashboards-logo.svg")}
            alt="Büyük Bilgi Bankası"
          />
          {!hideLogoText && (
            <span className="d-none d-md-inline ml-1">
              Büyük Bilgi Bankası
            </span>
          )}
        </div>
```

Comment: It will might help you. https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-encoding-plugin

Comment: Yes, I've seen this page but how can I setup webpack config? I couldn't find config file

Comment: I think this file has charset for your app. https://github.com/DesignRevision/shards-dashboard-react/blob/master/.editorconfig

Comment: Thank you, very much. I guess it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I added this file project and saved again. So, its worked. Thanks @Nitish Thakrar

https://github.com/DesignRevision/shards-dashboard-react/blob/master/.editorconfig